# Second part of program is not running c#

Tags: visual-studio-2012

when i run this program, static void Main2() runs but not static void Main4(), im not sure why. also, i have multiple c# class files in my visual studio 2015rc console application and only one of them runs but i have multiple c classes, how does anyone run multiple c classes? and how do i control which class runs first?

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApplication1.Examples
{
class ExampleOne
{
    static void Main2()
    {
        Console.Write("Please Enter Name 1 ");
        string name1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Please Enter Name 2 ");
        string name2 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("The First Name is " + name1  +" "+ name2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Main4()
    {

        Console.Write("Please Enter Number 1 ");
       int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please Enter Number 2 ");
        int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int z = x + y;

        Console.Write("The numbers are: " + x + " " + y);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Write(z);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Multiple Main's in one class = DO NOT; What you want to do is run methods or instantiate classes using ONE main

Comment: Try to in Main2() after console.ReadKey() call the Main4(); function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you create functions instead of Main() classes.

if you want to pursue that Main() classes, remove the "static"  variable before the Main() classes, use public instead

Comment: yep, do not use multiple Main() in one class

Comment: i like this, i moved the function in Main4 inside Main2, fixed the issue